# Code is run but no output, what is my mistake?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
 Protected Sub View_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(TryCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument)
        Dim lsfilename As String
        Dim lsfilepath As String
        Dim savePath As String = "c:/Users/Administrator.VCIDEX3/Downloads"

        Dim embed As String = "<object data=""{0}"" type=""application/pdf"" align=""center"" width=""500px"" height=""600px"">"
        embed += "</object>"
        objdbconn.OpenConn()
        msSQL = "select Id,FileName,FilePath from tblfiles where Id='" & id & "'"
        objODBCDataReader = objdbconn.GetDataReader(msSQL)
        If objODBCDataReader.HasRows = True Then
            objODBCDataReader.Read()
            lsfilename = objODBCDataReader.Item("FileName").ToString
            lsfilepath = objODBCDataReader.Item("FilePath").ToString
        End If
        msSQL = " select * from tblfiles where id='" & id & "'  "
        ltEmbed.Text = String.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("'" & savePath & "' /q.pdf"))
        objdbconn.CloseConn()
    End Sub




<asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" />
```

> here I tried to view a PDF file using literal, the code is executed and I
>   got `c:/Users/Administrator.VCIDEX3/Downloads/q.pdf` correctly but
>   the file is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

You have two parameter placeholders in your text, i.e. {0} and {1}, but you only provide one value, i.e. the result of `ResolveUrl`.  If the text is expecting two values to be replaced then you need to provide two values.

Comment: ok , i remove {1} but i get this url c:/Users/Administrator.VCIDEX3/Downloads i ill use embed in htm to vie that file in that code  <asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" /> but the output is not show but coding is execute no error what i do ?

Comment: That is a different issue.  The question you asked about has been resolved.  If you have a new issue, ask a new question and provide information relevant to that question.